# logback set log level at runtime per request

Tags: slf4j, logback-classic

I am using logback.xml (slf4j) for logging in my application.
In production, my logger is set at ERROR mode.

I want to change the log level to "DEBUG" for a particular request which has my test data ( example: msisdn is "1234512345" ); for all other requests, the log set level should be at ERROR.

So,  can i change the log level per request basis and how?